# Append to compressed log

Tags: logging, gzip, less, cat

There is a couple of z-utilities (`zless`, `zcat`), which are able to read contents of zipped file in transparent manner.

Is it possible to append to compressed log file (in either format, not necessarily gzip)?

I want something like the following (`ztee` is imaginary utility with functionality of interest):

```
echo "[ $( date ) ] message" | ztee -a file.log.gz
```

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: @Seth tried what?

Comment: Well you actually do have a command right there. Did you try to run it, assuming `ztee` exists? Also have a look at the [man page for zless](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zless) as it might give you some more leads.

Comment: @Seth Where have I command? `ztee` not exists. I know about `zless` existance - how can it help me to solve the problem? If I run imaginary pseudocode in the shell, then I definitely get an error. For sure. Surely I didn't try to run it. Actually assumption of `ztee` existence gives nothing to me in real life.

Comment: You didn't make it clear. The man page kind of shows you what `zless` is actually doing (more or less an alias for `gzip`). Grawity already took his time to explain what you can do and you accepted it as an answer. The `gzip` man page has examples that pretty much do the same.

Comment: @Seth and.... what? You just listed the trivia. What do you want?

Comment: I'm providing feedback in order for you to ask better questions going forward and the reason I mentioned the man page.

Comment: @Seth Thank you. Maybe the problem (of mine) in the language barrier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it's useless.

---

Some compressed file formats – including the ones used by `gzip`, `bzip2`, and `xz` – **do** support concatenation natively. (It *may* require explicit opt-in when using low-level APIs, but command-line decompressors accept it by default.)

```
echo "test 1" | gzip >> log.txt.gz
echo "test 2" | gzip >> log.txt.gz
echo "test 3" | tee >(gzip >> log.txt.gz)
echo "test 4" | (tee /dev/fd/3 | gzip >> log.txt.gz) 3>&1
zcat log.txt.gz
```

(Note that e.g. `zcat` is literally just a shellscript wrapper for `gunzip`...)

**However,** this means that each log message is compressed individually, without taking into account all the previous contents. As a result, if you try to chain many short log messages, your compression ratios will be very, *very* poor. (In my tests compressing a random log file this way, the resulting file actually *grew* to 120% its original size, because of all the repeated "header" overhead.)

```
$ dmesg > test.log
$ cat test.log | gzip > test-single.log.gz
$ cat test.log | while read -r line; do
                     echo "$line" | gzip
                 done > test-concat.log.gz
$ du -h test*
500K     test-concat.log.gz
416K     test.log
64K      test-single.log.gz
```

To my knowledge, there is no tool which would support loading the existing compressed file's headers and use it to compress new data. To achieve this, you would need to run a persistent `gzip` process and periodically feed it logs via stdin. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# open a subprocess (the bash equivalent of 'popen')
coproc LOG { gzip >> log.txt.gz; }

echo "doing stuff" >&${LOG[1]}
echo "doing more stuff" >&${LOG[1]}
echo "still doing stuff" >&${LOG[1]}

# close its stdin to finish compression
exec {LOG[1]}>&-
```

In "standard" shell, you could achieve the same using named pipes, or even more simply redirecting *the whole script* through `gzip`. (Just print the same message once to stdout and once to stderr, and you have your `tee`.)

---

Further information on compressed stream concatenation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005114/fast-concatenation-of-multiple-gzip-files
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Advanced-usage.html

  > Multiple compressed files can be concatenated. In this case, gunzip will extract all members at once. If one member is damaged, other members might still be recovered after removal of the damaged member
- https://tukaani.org/xz/format.html

  > Concatenation: Just like with .gz and .bz2 files, it is possible to concatenate .xz files as is. The decompressor can decompress a concatenated file as if it was a regular single-stream .xz file.

Comment: So with minimal usefulness it is required to reread whole the file. I don't want to loose intermediate progress in case of accidental system failure.

Comment: Then just don't compress active logs in the first place. The more complexity the more likely it is to somehow fail.

Comment: Eventually I came to the same conclusions. Thank you.